# Mod_rewriter simple redirect

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I need some help with mod_rewirter

My URL have this structure
http://mydomain.com/post.php?id=122/year/month/title/

i need to have the new link:

http://mydomain.com/year/month/title/
how can i do this with mod_rewriter, please can you help me! 
thank you

Comment: I bet you don't want the id always has the same value. Am i right?

Comment: Hello, my pages are dynamic, and all of them have a specific id. but i dont need the id in the title. is this possible ?

Comment: Then you have to edit your question. The url you wanted is like: http://mydomain.com/122/year/month/title/

Comment: the url i need is : http://mydomain.com/year/month/title/  without the ID

Comment: Doesn't post.php get values from database in order to id? According to your url structure, post.php needs id. So, you have to add it too.

Comment: Yes it gets values from database . but  as i have seen in wordpress this is possible, to get an url without id.. wordpress is using mod_rewriter too. Can some  one help how to get the kind of url i need ? Thank you

Comment: Because wordpress gets values in order to their dates but your php file needs id. If you add a query to get values in order to date then your url will be meaningful

Comment: let suppose i can get values in order to date , how can i make the mod_rewriter? thnx

Answer (score 1):

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php it is a nice page to learn apache mod_rewrite engine.

And i'll give you an example while i'm still insisting that you have to add id on your seo friendly url

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) http://mydomain.com/post.php?id=$1/$2/$3/$4/ [NC]
```

If we suppose you can get values in order to date

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) http://mydomain.com/post.php?year=$1&month=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

Also, you can validate any regex on this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html or that: http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex